# Client-side checking of a file input have a correct image file format

Tags: javascript, forms, file-upload

I wonder if there is a way of checking correct fileformat and size of an image using javascript?

I have a signup form and it is mandatory to upload an image before using the application:

```
<form action='signUp.php' method POST>
    choose your image: <input type='file'></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to check the file size with just javascript, but you should be able to check the file format of the file selected by simply grabbing the value of that input field and grabbing the last part. Like so, say you have this tag in your HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="afile" />
```

In your javascript you could have a function like this, and refer to it when the form is submitted:

```
function check_filetype(){
    var filename = document.getElementById('afile').value;
    return filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
}
```

Comment: Right. The reason for this is that JavaScript is fairly locked down as far as what it can do with the client's computer. The file system is more or less inaccessible. I'm sure that you can think of some very bad things that people could do if browsers gave JavaScript more freedom.

Comment: @voithos Yeah after a little google-fu there are some methods of finding the file size with activex or flash, but none of them are elegant solutions.

Comment: Right, and remember ActiveX is completely proprietary to Internet Explorer, and won't even function at all in other browsers.

Comment: File Size can be validated in Html5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212041/it-is-possible-to-validate-the-size-and-type-of-input-file-in-html5