# Is it possible to validate the size and type of input=file in html5

Tags: html, validation, file-io

I was reading this http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.file.html, but I only found the "accept" attribute.

I tried this

```
<input type="file" name="imagefilename" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" />
```

Is it possible client-side validation of file size?

I found this technique for IE

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getSize()
{
    var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var filepath = document.upload.file.value;
    var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
    var size = thefile.size;
    alert(size + " bytes");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="upload">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="button" value="Size?" onClick="getSize();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to do the same using [html5 filesystem api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) ?

**UPDATE**

I could do this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9bhcB/)):

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form >
        <input type=file id=f max-size=32154 >
        <input type=submit>
    </form>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        var isOk = true;
        $('input[type=file][max-size]').each(function(){
            if(typeof this.files[0] !== 'undefined'){
                var maxSize = parseInt($(this).attr('max-size'),10),
                size = this.files[0].fileSize;
                isOk = maxSize > size;
                return isOk;
            }
        });
        return isOk;
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

It is working fine, but I think It will be better to a native html5 attr to validate

Comment: this.files[0].fileSize => this.files[0].size

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I could do this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9bhcB/)):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form >
        <input type="file" id="f" data-max-size="32154" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        var isOk = true;
        $('input[type=file][data-max-size]').each(function(){
            if(typeof this.files[0] !== 'undefined'){
                var maxSize = parseInt($(this).attr('max-size'),10),
                size = this.files[0].size;
                isOk = maxSize > size;
                return isOk;
            }
        });
        return isOk;
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: According to developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File.fileSize , `fileSize` has been deprecated. Instead everyone should use `size`.

Answer (score 52):

```
    <form  class="upload-form">
        <input class="upload-file" data-max-size="2048" type="file" >
        <input type=submit>
    </form>
    <script>
$(function(){
    var fileInput = $('.upload-file');
    var maxSize = fileInput.data('max-size');
    $('.upload-form').submit(function(e){
        if(fileInput.get(0).files.length){
            var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size; // in bytes
            if(fileSize>maxSize){
                alert('file size is more then' + maxSize + ' bytes');
                return false;
            }else{
                alert('file size is correct- '+fileSize+' bytes');
            }
        }else{
            alert('choose file, please');
            return false;
        }

    });
});
    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9bhcB/2/

Comment: Thanx, but I've made a generic solution.

Comment: @Sergey Gospodarets Nice anser, worked for my code. Question, how can I also check the type of the file? I try something like `alert('type'+fileInput.get(0).files[0].type);` but no result. And unfortunatelly no errors in the console. Thanks

Comment: @LasseEspeholt .fileSize is deprecated, but I'm using .size instead, which is valid ( http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/ )

Comment: @slevin .type should work. Working demo http://codepen.io/malyw/pen/nyvEt

Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182968/determining-unknown-content-types-with-the-html5-file-api to understastand, when .type could return an empty string.

Comment: @SergeyGospodarets Ahh sorry about that, this comment was on the wrong answer. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

In React js you can perform like this

```
const handleFileUpload = (e) => {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    let fileType = file.type; // image/jpeg
    let fileSize = file.size; // 3MB

    if (fileSize > 5 * 1000000) {
      // fileSize > 5MB then show popup message
      alert(
        `File size is too large, please upload image of size less than 5MB.\nSelected File Size: ${
          fileSize / 1000000
        }MB only`
      );
      return;
    }
  };
```

```
<input
        type="file"
        accept="image/*"
        title="upload file smaller than 5MB"
        placeholder="upload file smaller than 3MB"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

if your using php for the backend maybe you can use this code.

```
// Validate image file size
if (($_FILES["file-input"]["size"] > 2000000)) {
    $msg = "Image File Size is Greater than 2MB.";
    header("Location: ../product.php?error=$msg");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: op asks about client side validation