# input type='file' how to control the images quality

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, ionic-framework

input type='file' , when I use it in hybirdApp how to control the images quality.
I use ionic and cordova to build app, use angular-file-upload to choose pictures and upload to my serve.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help others answer your question, please provide some code showing what you've tried so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You could simply crop the image before uploading to the server.

**Here are some cropping libraries.**

Plain JS: https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/

Framework (Angular): https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper

Answer (score -1):

You can validate the file type and file size of the input type='file', so if you are trying to make people upload images which are of a minimum (or maximum) resolution you could get the file size of the selected image, and then based on its file type (jpg/png etc) you could set a minimum/maximum filesize to be the approximate/average value of the smallest/largest image size you desire.

See this for code examples of getting this information: [It is possible to validate the size and type of input=file in html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212041/it-is-possible-to-validate-the-size-and-type-of-input-file-in-html5)