# file_field_tag: only upload zip file less than specific size - RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to upload only zip files of size less than 100MB. Following some resources, I have mentioned `size 1` but I am not sure if it is 1MB, 1GB or what exactly it is? And I am still able upload zip files of any size.

```
= file_field_tag 'photos_zip_file', accept: '.zip', size: 1
```

My main concern is that if there is a way to upload the specific size files from from-end code only?

Comment: Are you using CarrierWave for upload or ActiveStorage or something else?

Comment: Using CarrierWave

Comment: check this answer for client side validation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212041/is-it-possible-to-validate-the-size-and-type-of-input-file-in-html5

Answer (score 0):

As you are using CarrierWave I suggest to add validation server side.

So in your model add:

```
validate :size_validation

private

def size_validation
  errors[:photo_zip_file] << "should be less than 100MB" if photo_zip_file.size > 100.megabytes
end
```

Hope it's help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Carrierwave wiki](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Validate-image-file-size):

```
def size_range
  1..100.megabytes
end
```

Or use [file validator](https://github.com/musaffa/file_validators)

```
validates :photos_zip_file, file_size: { less_than: 100.megabytes }, file_content_type: { allow: 'application/zip' }
```